# iOS – Subclass UITableViewCell to mimic UITableViewCellStyleValue1

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to have the look of `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` but instead of just only having text on the left side I want to have a small image and then text to the right of it. How would I subclass `UITableViewCell` to get the default look of `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` but with my small adjustment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inherit UITableViewCell you can create, for example, your own init method:

```
@implementation BIDCell {
UITableViewCellStyle style1;
}

- (id)init:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    style1 = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
    self = [super initWithStyle:style1 reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    //your code
    }
return self;
}
```

And whe you will initialize your cell you will need only `reuseIdentifier`, cell style is already setted.